# How does s3 data lake handle database updated rows?

Tags: bigdata

I'm new to this data lake concept. 
I want to move 4 different MySQL databases into an S3 data lake so I can use the Redshift spectrum to query it. A lot of these databases have tables that do update operations. 
What are the best practices to handle that in S3? Or is S3 data lake not the right solution for this.

I've tried writing spark job to pull incremental data based on created_at and updated_at columns and put that in S3. The issue with this is I'll have duplicate rows if there is an update operation.

The other way I've done it is to copy the whole table over each time.

I've also tried partitioning the S3 buckets by hours, so if the update is within an hour, I'll just delete that bucket and reprocess that hour.

It just seems very hacky to me. 
Is this not a common use case? 
What are the best practices around this?

Comment: This is one of the big gotchas of big data - at sufficient scale, you're basically append-only. Otherwise you just have a big database. You will end up setting up your lake consumers so that you use the latest copy of the record available in the lake, rather than presuming that there is just the one. This is common in big data - BigQuery, HDFS, and Kafka all operate without updates for just this reason.